# How to replace strings in text file with list values in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, replace

I have a text file containing data as:

```
****File1*****
a     jhk
b     hfd
file  f1.txt     ;file open
hh       dsfsd        
----
qqw      adas
file    f2.txt     ;file open
hjh     dfd


****File2*****
d     sdfsd
b     sdfsd
file   f3.txt     ;file open
sada     dsfsd        
----
qqw     sdfsd
file    f4.txt     ;file open
wqeq     dfd
```

I have a list

```
    files=['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt','d.txt']
```

I want to replace strings(files) in textfile with the values in list in order.
For example: I wish to replace 'f1.txt' in text file with 'a.txt' then 'f2.txt' with 'b.txt'... likewise.

What I have tried is:

```
fileName=input("Enter Input File Name: ")
f1=open(fileName,'r')
outFile=input("Enter Output File: ")
f2=open(outFile,'w')
nr=csv.reader((open("graphScript.csv")))
rn=0
b=[]
gFlag=0
global files
files=[]
for row1 in nr:
        b.append(row1)
        rn+=1
global nGraph
df=pd.read_csv("graphScript.csv")
files=list(df[df.columns[0]][4:])

for line in f1.readlines():
    word=line
    count = 0
    ----

    if re.search(r'/file',word):
        strplit=word.split()[1]
        for i in files:
            word=strplit.replace(strplit,i)
            f2.write(word)
    else:
           f2.write(word)
```

Whenever I run this code, Output appears as:

```
    ****File1*****
    a     jhk
    b     hfd
    a.txtb.txtc.txtd.txt
    hh       dsfsd        
    ----
    qqw      adas
    a.txtb.txtc.txtd.txt
    hjh     dfd


    ****File2*****
    d     sdfsd
    b     sdfsd
    a.txtb.txtc.txtd.txt
    sada     dsfsd        
    ----
    qqw     sdfsd
    a.txtb.txtc.txtd.txt
    wqeq     dfd
```

What I actually want the output to be :

```
****File1*****
a     jhk
b     hfd
file  a.txt     ;file open
hh       dsfsd        
----
qqw      adas
file    b.txt     ;file open
hjh     dfd


****File2*****
d     sdfsd
b     sdfsd
file   c.txt     ;file open
sada     dsfsd        
----
qqw     sdfsd
file    d.txt     ;file open
wqeq     dfd
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score -1):

Replace using `re.sub` once at a time.

```
f1=f1.read()
for i in files:
    f1=re.sub('f\d.txt',i,f1,1)
print(f1,file=f2)
```

Comment: What do you get